# Menu Toggle function is not working on eccomerce site

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I've been trying to troubleshoot this on my own but I already spent too many hours trying to figure it out. I couldn't add the images because idk how to on here but if someone could help me please. Or at least guide me in the right direction. My main.js is in a folder called js. My styles.css and html don't have folders but they seem to be working fine cause I know that matters as well.

```js
function menuToggle() {
  var MenuItems = document.getElementById("MenuItems");
  MenuItems.style.maxHeight = "0px";


  if (MenuItems.style.maxHeight == "0px") {
    MenuItems.style.maxHeight = "200px";
  } else {
    MenuItems.style.maxHeight = "0px";
  }
}
```

```css
.menu-icon {
  width: 28px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: none;
}


/*--- media query for menu ---*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 0;
    background: #333;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.5s;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    color: #fff;
  }
  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Gucci</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Assistant:wght@200;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>



</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">


    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="images/logogucci.png" width="125px">
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul id="MenuItems">
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Account</a></li>



          </ul>
        </nav>
        <img src="images/carticon.png" width="30px" height="30px">
        <img src="images/hamburger-menu-icon-transparent-1.jpg" class="menu-icon" onclick="menuToggle()">

      </div>
```

Comment: create images folder and inside images folder past carticon.png & hamburger-menu-icon-transparent-1.jpg image.

Comment: No I meant that I don't know how to add images on here stackoverflow so you could see the full working code snippet. What my question really is why my menu won't toggle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your toggle function is that you're setting the height to 0px every time you toggle

You need to remove this line:

`MenuItems.style.maxHeight = "0px";`

```js
function menuToggle() {
  var MenuItems = document.getElementById("MenuItems");

  if (MenuItems.style.maxHeight == "0px") {
    MenuItems.style.maxHeight = "200px";
  } else {
    MenuItems.style.maxHeight = "0px";
  }
}
```

```css
.menu-icon {
  width: 28px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: none;
}


/*--- media query for menu ---*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 0;
    background: #333;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.5s;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    color: #fff;
  }
  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">


  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/logogucci.png" width="125px">
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul id="MenuItems">
          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Account</a></li>



        </ul>
      </nav>
      <img src="images/carticon.png" width="30px" height="30px">
      <img src="images/hamburger-menu-icon-transparent-1.jpg" class="menu-icon" onclick="menuToggle()">
```